# Single Frame image from Camera Preview Android

Tags: java, android, camera, photo

I want to be able to take a snapshot of a preview camera screen being displayed on a SurfaceView. I know it has something to do with the `onPreviewFrame()` method and this returns a byte array in YUV format but I have no idea how to call the onPreviewFrame() method on it's own.

I have used it in conjunction with `Camera.setPreviewCallback()` but this is a continuous thing that keeps generating the image, I need it to do it once on an `onClick()`, to pretty much take a photo without making the preview window stop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anybody else with a similar problem to this I solved it by using the `setOneShotPreviewCallback()` method on the camera object to give me a `byte[]` with the information for the image. with that its can be used to create a YUV and then compressed to bitmap or whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Capture the preview image into a canvas and hold a lock to it. You can then easily save to a BitMap
Refer this post for complete explanation with sample code
 http://www.anddev.org/using_camerapreview_to_save_a_picture_on_disk-t226.html